# Does Magento have a logic for levels of being "logged in"?

Tags: login, cookie, magento-1.4

I am new to magento but have programmed for years.  Does Magento have a concept of "presumed identity based on cookies and/or computer, but not logged in"?  Or perhaps a concept of "login remembered but, not authorized to change account or billing information unless they 'really' log in"?

Additionally, does Magento have a system to identify "logged in but not email-verified yet", and is this a separate condition from the above, or are they lumped in as on single series of values?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does Magento have a concept of "presumed identity based on cookies and/or computer, but not logged in"?*

In general, no, Magento does not have this concept beyond previous store scope choice.

> *...does Magento have a system to identify "logged in but not email-verified yet", and is this a separate condition from the above?*

Sort of. It is possible through configuration to require users to verify their account via emailed link, but note that this setting is configurable per website. A proper check can be seen in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::authenticate()`:

```
public function authenticate($login, $password)
{
    $this->loadByEmail($login);
    if ($this->getConfirmation() && $this->isConfirmationRequired()) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed.'),
            self::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED
        );
    }
    //...
}

public function isConfirmationRequired()
{
    if ($this->canSkipConfirmation()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (self::$_isConfirmationRequired === null) {
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId() ? $this->getStoreId() : null;
        self::$_isConfirmationRequired = (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_IS_CONFIRM, $storeId);
    }

    return self::$_isConfirmationRequired;
}
```